# Failing to connect dynamic widget to slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I'm trying to create a Password manager with Qt, and I'm struggling with signals and slots.

Here is a function that creates a dynamic widget:

```
void QtPasswordTransfer::ShowPasswordLine(std::map<std::string, std::string>* FileMap)
{
    QVBoxLayout* LayoutForText = qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(ui.Resourses->layout());
    QVBoxLayout* LayoutForPasswordButtons = qobject_cast<QVBoxLayout*>(ui.PasswordsButtons->layout());
    for (auto Iterator{ FileMap->begin() }; Iterator != FileMap->end(); ++Iterator)
    {
        QLabel* PasswordSourceWidget = new QLabel(Iterator->first.c_str());

        QFont SourceFont{ PasswordSourceWidget->font()};
        SourceFont.setPointSizeF(13);
        PasswordSourceWidget->setFont(SourceFont);
        LayoutForText->insertWidget(2, PasswordSourceWidget);

        QPushButton* PasswordButtonWidget = new QPushButton("Copy password");
        LayoutForPasswordButtons->insertWidget(2, PasswordButtonWidget);
        connect(PasswordButtonWidget, SIGNAL(QPushButton::clicked()), this, SLOT(CopingPassword(Iterator->second)));
    }
}
```

This function takes password and source of it from map, create `QLabel` and `QPushButton` from it.

But when clicking the created buttons, the signals do not seem to work at all, before that I tried to connect those widgets to another signal:

```
QObject::connect(PasswordSourceWidget, SIGNAL(DeleteDynamicWidget()), this, SLOT(DelitingWithoutClicks(FileMap->size())));
```

to delete them, then used:

```
emit DeleteDynamicWidget
```

and none of the widgets I connected them to it were reacted.

Do I need to emit a signal for every widget?

What am I doing wrong? The system looks pretty simple:

- You create a reaction(slot) for signal
- You emit a signal
- You get the reaction of widgets

but when debugging, I found out that after emitting a signal, the program never connects  it to a slot.

I've tried some solutions that I found in similar questions, but they did not work for me:

- Putting `int` as a parameter for every signal.
- Using `QObject::connect` even inside of a method, but when debugging, it seems like it gets into connect function, but no reaction when emitting.

Comment: `SLOT` macro takes a function signature, not a function call. You seem to believe that you can "pass" parameters to the function within `SLOT`, and somehow magically `connect` will extract and store them for you, and pass them along to your function when the signal actually fires. That ain't how it works.

Comment: That said, `connect` can also take lambdas, and lambdas can in fact capture values. Try this: `std::string password = Iterator->second; connect(PasswordButtonWidget, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [=]() { CopingPassword(password); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid `SLOT` and `SIGNAL` MACROS which does stringification...

`SLOT(CopingPassword(Iterator->second))` should be `[=](){ CopingPassword(Iterator->second); }`.

so

```
connect(PasswordButtonWidget, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [=](){ CopingPassword(Iterator->second); });
```

Care, `Iterator` should not be invalidated neither...
else you might capture `Iterator->second` directly:

```
connect(PasswordButtonWidget, &QPushButton::clicked,
        this, [password = Iterator->second, this](){ CopingPassword(password); });
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation and code example, now it works fine. But how can I use custon signals? I mean if I want the same button to be deleted when I write 'emit CustomSignal()' . Here is how I think its need to be, after reading your answer: ' connect(PasswordButtonWidget, &QtPasswordTransfer::DeleteDynamicWidget, this, [=]() {DelitingWithoutClicks(); }); ' 
But IDE says that this does not match parameter list, same if I use SIGNAL macro. Thanks.